# How does Liu intend his readers to compute $H^0(X,\Omega^1_{X/k})$ of this scheme?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, schemes, sheaf-theory, duality-theorems, projective-schemes

In the chapter on duality theory in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, there is the following exercise. I'm having trouble seeing how one can apply the duality theory developed in Liu to solve it.

> $4.2$. Let $k$ be a field, and let $F=x^n+y^n+z^n\in k[x,y,z]$, where
>   $n\ge 1$ is prime to $\operatorname{char}(k)$. Determine
>   $H^0(X,\Omega^1_{X/k})$ for $X=V_+(F)\subset \mathbb P^2_k$.

The preceding chapter was very theoretical, and I'm having trouble understanding how to apply the theory to do actual computations. In particular, it contains a lot of duality-like lemmas and I'm not sure which one to actually apply. To be honest, I don't understand it very well, and I was hoping doing something concrete with it would help.

I understand there are many different ways to compute cohomology groups. I would like to do this using the tools developed so far by Liu. In particular, he does not talk about Euler sequences like Hartshorne does. (It is possible they *are* in the book in disguise, but I do not see them. Please correct me if this is the case.) I would also appreciate any suggestions for elementary ways to use duality to compute this cohomology group. Thanks.

(The cohomology theory Liu uses is Čech cohomology.)

**Edit.** The answer below sketches a simple way to do this without any duality at all. My question is now this: What is this question doing in a chapter on duality? Does a duality argument make it even easier?

**Edit 2.** I think I see what was intended now. Once must use Corollary $4.14$ and proceed as in the following examples. The key observation here is that it suffices to compute the canonical sheaf $\omega_{X/k}$, since the canonical sheaf is isomorphic to $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ in this situation. Corollary $4.14$ then gives the tools necessary to compute $\omega_{X/k}$. Thinking in terms of duality was the wrong approach.

Comment: If only there were someone here who could know what goes on inside Liu's mind...

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh If only!

Comment: Less facetiously, I don't have access to Liu's book, so I won't try to guess what the "appropriate" solution is. But let me ask: since this is in the chapter on duality, what does duality tell you about the vector space you want to compute?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I don't know. As I said, there are a lot of duality-like lemmas and I'm having trouble teasing out an applicable statement. There's a lot of stuff about r-dualizing sheaves and the trace map, but I'm not sure how to put the pieces together.

Comment: Guess: It has dimension $1/2(n-1)(n-2)$.

Comment: Good guess, @Matt!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H^0$ is just global sections, so he is askign you to describe the module of globally defined differential forms on your curve $X$.

- Find an open covering by affine open sets of the curve, and find the coordinate ring of those sets
- On each of them, find a presentation of the module of Kähler differentials.
- Finally, see which differentials on those open sets extend to the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

1) Forget about  cohomology: $H^0(X,\Omega^1_{X/k})$ just means $\Omega^1_{X/k}(X)$, the vector space of global sections of the sheaf $\Omega^1_{X/k}$.

2) Forget about duality, which has nothing to do with the exercise.
 The exercise is probably attached  to section 6.4.2, devoted to the canonical sheaf.

3) The curve $X$ is smooth since $n$ is not divisible by $\text {char} (k)$.
Since it has degree $n$, its genus is  $g=\frac {(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$.
And thus the dimension of the $k$-vector space    $H^0(X,\Omega^1_{X/k})$ is $g=\frac {(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$, and this  is a possible  solution to the exercise.

**Caveat**
Since I have not read this great book systematically but only consulted it, I am not sure what solution the author had in mind (maybe he wants his reader to use theorem 4.9 (a), the adjunction formula, which would also provide a solution)
However I guarantee the correctness of the formula I described in point 3) .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain a little more how the adjunction formula provides a solution? We want to determine $\omega_{X/k}\cong \Omega^1_{X/k}$, and to use the adjunction formula we must interpose some scheme $Z$ between $X$ and $k$. I guess $\mathbb P^2_k$ is the obvious choice, but I do not see how it simplifies the calculations. (I will upvote when my votes recharge. Thanks again.)

Comment: Briefly: $\Omega^1_{X/k}=\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2/k}\otimes_{\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2/k}} O_X(n)=O_X(n-3)$